# Android Studio 3.0 Databinding reference code not genereted by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm having problem with Android Studio 3.0 and combination of kotlin and data binding. I'm not sure why, but option Settings -> Editor -> Data Binding -> Reference code generated by android studio is not working as it should be.

I've tried it on different AS 3.0 versions (Canary 3, Canary 5, Canary 6) with different kotlin (1.1.2-3, 1.1.3, 1.1.3-2) and databinding compiler ver. To be sure I have even created clean project and the same problem occurs. I'm sure that the problem lies in kotlin and databinding combination because in the same project databinding in java class is working just fine, files generated by databinding are updated with every change in .xml file.

I'm not going to paste my every gradle content file here because I have tried a lot of combination versions of kotlin and data binding. Below is one of them.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dawidj.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Databinding
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



buildscript {
    ext.android_plugin_version = '2.4.0-alpha7'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've noticed that while i'm in java file after click (ctrl + click) on file generated by Data binding ex.:activity_main.xml -> ActivityMainBinding.java my screen is being moved directly to activity_main.xml file. After the same action in Kotlin class screen is being moved to ActivityMainBinding.java file.

It's very annoying problem becasue with every change in .xml file I'm forced to rebuild project in order to use data binding.

Any kind of help or information will be appreciated

EDIT: Invalidate caches / restart helps only to first project build. If I create new .xml layout it's working fine until project build.

Comment: You might get better answers if you state your problem more clearly, I found it a little cumbersome to understand what's actually broken for you. Unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Comment: Android Studio -> Settings -> Editor -> Data Binding -> here you can find two options. 

@Uli First, Reference code generated by android studio should update file that extends ViewDataBinding generated by data binding library every time when User change layout.xml file. Unfortunatly while using kotlin with data binding it's not working.

In order to update file generated by data binding i'm forced to rebuild project every time to "get" changes.

Comment: I'd put something like this in the first paragraph, preferably the first sentence - it provides the context of your question and describes your core problem right away: When I use Android Databinding in combination with Kotlin, the code that is auto-generated from the layout file fails to automatically update when I change the layout file.

Comment: You could consider creating an issue on the Google issue tracker, unless one exists already.

Comment: I have searched Google issue tracker and there it is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62330894

Someone else reported it, issue is still present. Unfortunately I dont have permissions in issue tracker and I am unable to comment it.

Thank for your advice.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I stopped using databinding cause of this bug in my project. I was wasting too much time for this. If you'll go to this issue in issuetracker you can see that no one answered till now.

Answer (score -1):

Add following in you `app build.gradle`

`android {
    /// Existing Code
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}`

This may help.

Comment: I have already tried that, it did not helped me. It's worth to add that generateStubs is an option that existed in the old kapt implementation and is decrepated now.